# c++11 template type aliases to reduce pain

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, clang

Does C++11 provide means to shorten kiloline-long templated class names (std:: as well as my own types)?

This would reduce the pain for deciphering and pretty-printing messages. I'd like to define custom aliases that replace the expanded template type names with unique and well-defined alternatives.

Utilizing `typedef` or `using` does not help as the compiler and `gdb` will still print the full type name. The aliases should be possible for `stl` as well as for custom templated types. Ideally `gcc`, `clang` and `gdb` should use the custom names then.

Answer (score 3):

No, the language itself provides no way to alter how tools display names, that's outside the scope of the standard, and is not consistently handled by different tools.

GCC has a `-fno-pretty-templates` option which adjusts how template specializations are shown in diagnostics.

You can define [Type Printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Type-Printing-API.html#Type-Printing-API) in Python to tell GDB how to print your type. I've written a few for libstdc++ so that GDB will print `std::vector<X>` not `std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> >`. It doesn't affect the types shown in compiler diagnostics, only in GDB.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases I've reduced the pain by replacing a `using` or `typedef` with inheritance; e.g. instead of `using MyType = MyTemplate<MyTraits<Blah>>` doing

```
struct MyType : MyTemplate<MyTraits<Blah>>
{
  // possibly some stuff
};
```

Uses of `MyType` in the latter case will be just that, where as a type alias (`using` or `typedef`) the compiler and debugger will print out long complex types that can sometimes be less informative, while in the latter case it will just print `MyType`. The `possibly some stuff` is the fly in the ointment as inheritance has now been introduced.

Comment: won't that lead to compiler warnings about virtual destructors?

Comment: @mic_e, only if you use `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` or the deeply flawed `-Weffc++` option. Don't do that. `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` is better in nearly every way and is enabled by `-Wall`

Comment: I mainly use this in generic programming, where these complex signatures come up in spades. No virtual functions in those cases.